# Cython create array of array / list of lists , but should be used inside a gil

Tags: python, c++, cython

I want to create an array of arrays . Like ,

```
[ [ 'hello', 'world' ] , ['hello'] , ['how' , 2, 5 ] ]
```

So, the size of the internal arrays are not fixed . Finally , it shouldn't be a Python object. Because , i need to use it inside gil for some manipulation . What i got is follows, which can be used inside "with nogil" , I guess. But, how to modify the following A matrix, so that I can add dynamic sub arrays .

```
%%cython --cplus
import numpy


def thing(int m, int n):
    cdef int i, j
    cdef object[:, :] A = numpy.empty((m, n), dtype=object)

for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    for j in range(A.shape[1]):
        A[i, j] = numpy.zeros(min(i, j))

return A
x =  thing(5,3)  

for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(x.shape[1]):
        x[i][j] = add some values ######
```

Comment: What are you trying to do and what is keeping you from doing it?

Comment: @PatrickMaupin - Here the matrix A is initialized using m and n. What if , my n is varying . ?

Comment: It's very confusing, because (a) your code is not formatted correctly; (b) you say you want to use things _inside_ the GIL; and (c) you say they shouldn't be Python objects.  "Inside" doesn't really characterize GIL operations, but to the extent it does, a native English speaker would interpret that to mean "while the GIL is held."  There is no reason to use non-Python objects while the GIL is being held.

Comment: @PatrickMaupin - What I meant is follows Patrick .   I need to assign the values inside a list, which will be a list ( list of lists ). These lists inside are not coming with pre-detrmined size. For eg:  [ [1,2] , [1,2,3] ] . So, in the above code it is done using fixed sub arrays ( sub lists ) size. Now, I need to make use of this list of list inside " with nogil " function . So, it sholudn't be a Python object .

Comment: `with nogil` is the opposite of `inside gil` so you should probably modify the question to reflect this, and should probably modify your example to include this -- your example doesn't show this at all.  Next question -- are you going to be allocating or deallocating or resizing the arrays inside your `with nogil` code?  (If not, please explain why you think they need to be non-Python objects.)

Comment: @PatrickMaupin - I need a list of list, that should be used inside 'with nogil"

Comment: I don't think you can do it, since your arrays are made up arbitrary Python objects. Why is it so important that the code runs in `with nogil:` blocks?

Comment: @DavidW - Why its important because , I am modifying a gensim package code. It is inside "with nogil". So, If I dont run inside "with nogil", multiprocessing doesn;t work properly I guess .

Comment: @SejaNair You can use `with gil:` inside `with nogil:` for the bits where you need it. It isn't ideal (you won't get full benefit of multiprocessing), but it will get things working. See http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#acquiring-and-releasing-the-gil

Comment: @DavidW - hi david. i some how managed to insert al the arrays like [1,2,3] , [4,5] into a np.PyArray_DATA                                                                     `cdef np.uint32_t *labelholder[MAX_SENTENCE_LEN]`                                  `labelholder[i] = <np.uint32_t *>np.PyArray_DATA(np.array([1,2,3))` . But it is not possible to see the values, as `print` statement is not working for non Python objects. I need a way to get the length of elements inside `labelholder[ i ]` on each iterations. is it possible ?

Comment: The numpy array you make is destroyed straight after it is created. That means your pointers point to memory which is no longer allocated and which can be used for something else (such as the next array you create). This isn't going to work.

Comment: @DavidW - Thanks alot . Can you suggest any good reading for Cython, assuming that I am not good at C or C++ . Python, I can manage .